# updating a table without redirecting the page

Tags: javascript, jsp, jquery, servlets

how to update a table without redirecting the page using javascript or jquery
this is my script

```
    function doubleclick(table,id1)
        {
            table.innerHTML="<input type=text name=tab onBlur=\"javascript:submitNewName(this,'"+id1+"');\" value=\""+table.innerHTML+"\">";
            table.firstChild.focus();

        }
        function submitNewName(text,id2)
        {
            text.parentNode.innerHTML=text.value;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'update',
            data:{text1:text.value,id:id2},
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"json",
            error:function(data)
            {
                alert('error')
            },
            success: function(data) 
            {
               // alert('updated!')
            }
        });  
        }
```

**html**

```
<td onDblclick="javascript:doubleclick(this,${item.id});">${item.filedesc}</td>
```

when i double click the table a edit box will appear within the column,an onblur event is called when the text box loses focus (by clicking outside the table), when it loses focus a update servlet should be called without redirecting the page. the update process should occur in the background

**Edit**

sorry for the late edit.did some editing to my script.i have posted my full working html and javascript code.solved this issue a month ago.users please check the code and suggest whether it can be improved more.

Comment: Your answer is in the tags, use ajax and jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery's ajax to achieve this. You can pass a callback method so it will notify you when the real update is complete.

This is a table cell, it can be anything, i am using div for this example:

```
<div id="table-cell" editing="0">Value</div>
```

js should be something like this

```
$('#table-cell').dblclick(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('editing') == '0')
    {
        // only trigger this when the cell is not in edit mode
        $(this).attr('editing',1);

        // show the input
        var input = $('<input type="text" value="'+$(this).html()+'">');
        $(this).html('');
        $(this).append(input);

        // bind blur event to input
        input.blur(function(){

            // update value from input to the table cell
            var value = $(this).val()
            $(this).parent().html(value);
            $(this).parent().attr('editing',0);

            // send the data to the server for update
            $.ajax({
                url: '/save_data/',
                data: {data:value},
                type:"POST",
                dataType:"json",
                error:function(data){alert('error')},
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('updated!')
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: will the above code work for <td>,i tried but it is not working

Comment: you can put <div> in the <td>, but it should work., and you should put this code in the $(function(){}); block, and have you include the jquery file in your html file? The information you provided is not enough for me to know what you current status is.

Comment: At least told me what you know and what you don't. from the code you provide I don't see anything related to jQuery.

Comment: the above code which i have pasted will invoke a textbox when the column is double clicked(only javascript),now as i told u before that i just want to update my table without redirecting the page and ur answer was the above code...the code is working after putting them inside $(function(){});

Comment: the script is working good but i cant modify more then one column

Comment: use class instead of id, <div class="cell"></div>, and use jquery selector $('.cell'), please refer to the [jquery documentation](http://www.jquery.com) for all api you can access.

Comment: can u look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103689/how-to-get-a-cell-values-when-its-corresponding-row-is-selected

Answer (score 0):

Use the $.post short hand method.

Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the $.ajax() method in jQuery. Retriving or posting content without triggering a page refresh is pretty straightforward.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/